# how to stop False alert in zabbix while monitoring any port or service in zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, alerts

My zabbix server sends alerts immediately when a service gets failed

my item for monitoring a port:

```
net.tcp.listen[80]
```

my trigger for monitoring a port:

```
{Testserver:net.tcp.listen[80].last()}=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem to be a false alert - you have configured your trigger to be too sensitive for your needs. While you didn't specify it, it seems that you want to make the trigger less sensitive. One way to do so:

```
{Testserver:net.tcp.listen[80].max(300)}=0
```

This will alert when the maximum value over last 300 seconds - 5 minutes - will be `0`. Thus it will alert when the service will be down continuously for 5 minutes. For convenience, you can also write it like this:

```
{Testserver:net.tcp.listen[80].max(5m)}=0
```

Comment: Tanks Richlv i fixed it and forget to share the answer anyway thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with the same thing using max() function

```
{Testserver:net.tcp.listen[80].max(#5)}=0
```

It which will check 5 consecutive checks if the value 0 remains same for all check it will trigger the alert

After that i increased the update interval in item default it is 30 seconds and i increased to 60 seconds so that it will check for 5 times every 1 minute